# What is the role of the startup.cs file?

Tags: owin, asp.net-core

I was trying to explore some ASP.NET-5 applications where I found the `startup.cs` file. Where we set out routing and all (of course not only for routing). I also see some demo where has shown the use of dependency injection [here](http://davidzych.com/2014/06/02/dependency-injection-in-asp-net-vnext/). So, I'm looking for answers to the below questions:

1. Why this `startup.cs` is? What it does?
2. What are the uses of this file?
3. What is the advantages of this?

And is there any good documentation to know the use of `startup.cs` in details. And why the application does not work if we change the class name 'Startup' to something else?

I do have very elementary idea about OWIN and pipeline. Please help me to find these answers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just repeating here what it's said in [Getting started with vNext](http://www.asp.net/vnext/overview/aspnet-vnext/getting-started-with-aspnet-vnext-and-visual-studio#startupcs)

> By default, the vNext hosting environment expects to find a startup class named Startup.
>   This class must contain a Configure method that takes an IBuilder parameter, and you configure the HTTP pipeline inside this Configure method. The empty project creates the class with nothing in the Configure method.

I would recommend you to take a look on [vNext Moving Parts](http://whereslou.com/) by Louis Dejardin since it explains a bit more about OWIN pipeline and vNext.

Sorry for not being of much help!